# Error in creating new dataframe from comparison of 2 dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe whose sample is as below:

df1:

```
                     Table                Field
0                    AOI                  AEDAT
1                    AEI                  AEDTZ
2                    AOI                  AEENR
3                    AEO                  AENAM
4                    AEO                  AEOST
```

df2:

```
        View       Field
0    Accounting 1  AEDAT
1    Accounting 1  AEDAT
2    Accounting 1  AEOST
3    Accounting 1  AEOST
```

What I want is compare `Field` columns of the 2 dataframe and if they are similar then in the third dataframe add the `View` field from the `df2` or else add `NA` as the row to the 3rd dataframe.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['view'])
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row['Field'] == row2['Field']:
            df3['view'].append(row2['View'])
```

When I run this code I get following error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

How do I correct this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `merge`

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', on  = 'Field')
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop Table and Field columns

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how ='left', on='Field').drop(['Table', 'Field'], axis=1 )
```